# wp_footer content appearing in admin area

Tags: hooks, footer

I am using the following code and I can't see anything in the footer of my site on the front end where the wp_footer function is called. It does, however, appear before the opening `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the admin area.

```
function xyz_footer_print() {
    echo 'footer script here';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', xyz_footer_print() );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're not using `add_action` correctly, what you've written is functionally the same as this:

```php
function xyz_footer_print() {
    echo 'footer script here';
}
$value = xyz_footer_print();
add_action( 'wp_footer', $value );
```

`xyz_footer_print()` immediately runs the function and returns nothing. As a result your `add_action` call says that on the `wp_footer` even, do nothing.

So you actually have 2 problems not 1, and if you check your PHP error log or install a tool such as query monitor/debug bar you'd see the warning/notice.

Instead actions always take the form:

```php
add_action( 'action name', 'callable type value, aka the name of function to run when the action happens' );
```

**That should give you enough information to fix this, but, it's the wrong way to put javascript in your footer.** You should instead use a JS file and enqueue it the way webelaine suggested.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to work that out and then forgot to update here! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is your `echo` is executing before anything else.

Try using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook instead of `wp_footer`, and instead of `echo` you will `wp_enqueue_script()`.

```
<?php
// Using a different hook:
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_411187_script' );

function wpse_411187_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        // "Handle" - a unique name for your script
        'xyz-footer-print',
        // Path to the JS file - adjust as needed
        plugins_url( 'build/xyz-footer-print.js', dirname( __DIR__ ) ),
        // Array of dependencies
        '',
        // Version number
        '1.0',
        // True to place the script the footer
        true
    );
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I would normally enqueue, but no access to ftp.